# How to install docker 1.9+ in CentOS 6.5?

Tags: linux, deployment, docker, centos, centos6

I'm now deploying on CentOS 6.5, and I'm now starting to use docker.

So, I follow the instructions on: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/centos/

No matter which method I follow to install, I get version of *1.7.1*.

```
[root@VM_72_235_centos ~]# docker version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d/1.7.1
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d/1.7.1
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

But now I run the command in the documentation:

```
docker network ls
```

With failure `docker: 'network' is not a docker command.`.

And I finally know that the network action is first introduced in 1.9.

So is there any way to install docker 1.9 in centos6 ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

CentOS 6 and RHEL 6 are no longer supported, and the last build for them is docker 1.7.1.

That page of the documentation (https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/centos/) also mentions;

> Docker runs on CentOS 7.X
>   Docker requires a 64-bit installation regardless of your CentOS version. Also, your kernel must be 3.10 at minimum, which CentOS 7 runs.

The kernel that those distro's are running on (2.6.x) is over 13 years old, and although newer features are back-ported to them by Red Hat, they lack certain options that are required by Docker, and have proven to be unstable, and unsuitable for production.

I encourage you to upgrade upgrade to CentOS 7.x if you want to (keep) using Docker.

Comment: Thank you, master. I will re-consider the situation seriously.