# Options to use latest docker on centos 6?

Tags: docker, centos6

I would like to try new features in latest version of docker (1.10 for now), like "docker networks" and "docker volume".

I have CentOs 6 and I CAN NOT upgrade OS due to some restrictions (understand I can use latest docker in centos 7). I do have root permission.

I am wondering what's the options I have to try latest docker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrade docker on CentOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472586/upgrade-docker-on-centos-7)

Comment: I am aware of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872129/how-to-install-docker-1-9-in-centos-6-5, I am currently thinking about docker in docker, because I can't upgrade my OS due to company policy, but it will be gread that some one can point me to a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a [static binary](https://github.com/docker/docker/releases/tag/v1.10.3) to run docker, but this is all at your own risk; CentOS 6 runs on kernel 2.6, which is 13 years old now. That kernel misses various things needed to run Docker (e.g. Overlay networking is not supported), and is known for having some issues.

Note that running docker-in-docker may get you around "installing" docker 1.10, but will still run on the same kernel, so you'll end up with the same issues

Comment: Thanks. I checked the kernel version, yes, event with /etc/redhat-release mentioned "CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)", the uname -r still print  2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64. sad :(

Comment: You should be able to update your kernel to a newer version; CentOS 7.2 ships with kernel 3.10 if I recall correctly

Answer (score 0):

You could install `docker-machine` and run `docker-machine upgrade default`

As described [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/upgrade/)

EDIT - This does not apply to you

But [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472586/upgrade-docker-on-centos-7) is possibly a duplicate of yours

Comment: Hey @Simon. I understand I can use latest docker in centOs 7, but as I mentioned, I can't upgrade my OS. I was thinking about docker in docker, but I would like to ask around to get even better ideas.

Comment: @MikeZhao All of the information in the linked question should also be applicable to centOS 6

Comment: please note that I am using centOS6, with can not install docker 1.9+. To reply your comment, I did some search, and found this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872129/how-to-install-docker-1-9-in-centos-6-5